# Google maps grey area

Tags: google-maps

Last weeks I had a problem with google maps. The map is loaded partially so I search about this but i couldn't find a solution.
I put this code on the resize event as some people suggest but still the same problem occurs.

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
});
```

map is the variable where i store the map object.

Could someone give me a tip?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've had the tip, so if it hasn't worked I think we'll need to see a little more. Can you mock up a jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: Works for me. Can show some code of your application (both HTML and javascript)?